# error TargetInvocationException when debugging (precisly when connecting to db) asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a `TargetInvocationException error` when debugging, it seems that there is not possible to connect to the database.
I don't know why, it suddenly doesn't work. I've just change the PC because of the expiration of the version of visual studio express I didn't know first that it is free.

So can somebody help me ?

Thank you for your help.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private static SimpleMembershipInitializer _initializer;
    private static object _initializerLock = new object();
    private static bool _isInitialized;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Ensure ASP.NET Simple Membership is initialized only once per app start
        LazyInitializer.EnsureInitialized(ref _initializer, ref _isInitialized, ref _initializerLock);
    }

  private class SimpleMembershipInitializer
    {
        public SimpleMembershipInitializer()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<UsersContext>(null);

            try
            {
                using (var context = new UsersContext())
                {
                    if (!context.Database.Exists())   // Here is thrown the error
                    {
                        // Create the SimpleMembership database without Entity Framework migration schema
                        ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.CreateDatabase();
                    }
                }
```

It is when I try to connect the defaultConnection database.

Comment: Post some code related to how you connect to the database.

Comment: I have edited my post when the error appear.

Comment: What does your `<membership>` config look like? Have you specified an EntityFramework-style connection string?

Comment: What's exception details? if(ex.InnerException != null) show(ex.InnerException.Message) ;) Most likely incorrect connection string, show connection string as well.

Comment: It is like that by default, when opening a new project.

Comment: Are you able to connect to database on your local machine? Are you able to create a new DB? Once you ascertain that, modify the default connection string to match with the DB credentials.

Comment: Thank you. It is ok, it was a default in the user profile. Really strange